# Meteor : Clear a field

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, semantic-ui, meteor-helper

i'm working with Semantic UI on Meteor. I have some modules like dropdown fields in my code. everything is on to get data, but I would like to clearthe dropdown like I could clear the text fields, but it doesn't work ..

Someone can help me please ?

here is my code:

```
Meteor.subscribe('brands');

Template.deliveryForm.helpers({
    brands: function() {
       return Brands.find({}, {fields: {'brand':1}});
    }
});

Template.deliveryForm.events({
  'submit .new-delivery': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var date = event.target.date.value;
    var brand = event.target.brand.value;
    var description = event.target.description.value;

    Deliveries.insert({
        date: date,
        brand: brand,
        description: description,
        createdAt: new Date()
    });

    event.target.date.value = "";
    event.target.brand.value = "";
    event.target.description.value = "";
  }
});

Template.deliveryForm.rendered = function(){
  $('select.dropdown').dropdown({ });
}
```

Thanks for the help

Here is the template code:

```
<template name="deliveryForm">
  <form class="ui form new-delivery">
    <div class="four inline fields">
        <div class="wide three field">
            <label>Date</label>
            <input type="date" name="date" placeholder="Date">
        </div>
        <div class="wide four field">
            <label>Marque</label>
            <select class="ui search dropdown" name="brand">
                <option value="">Selectionner Marque</option>
                {{#each brands}}
                    <option value="{{brand}}">{{brand}}</option>
                {{/each}}
                </select>
        </div>
        <div class="wide eight field">
            <label>Description</label>
            <input type="text" name="description" placeholder="Description">
        </div>
        <button class="ui button icon right labeled teal" type="submit" name="submit"><i class="right checkmark icon"></i>Valider</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>
```

Comment: Could you please provide a [MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com)?

Comment: Could you add your template code?

Comment: I just added the template code @GUISSOUMAIssam thanks :) I will try to do a MeteorPad

Comment: http://meteorpad.com/pad/KRJiPcYZRmtAaf3tw/Leaderboard, here is a meteorpad with the code only, and here is the github: https://github.com/guillaumeko/frenchys-manager, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Semantic UI dropdown docs](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#/usage), you can clear your dropdown this way:

```
Template.deliveryForm.rendered = function(){
  $('select.dropdown').dropdown('clear');
}
```

Hope this works :)

**EDIT**

Your code, and my example, needs to be wrapped inside `Meteor.defer` (some refs [1](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2176), [2](https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#how-do-i-animate-things-addingbeing-removed-from-collections), [3](https://kadira.io/academy/meteor-performance-101/content/make-your-app-faster#optimizing-http-calls-email-sending-and-third-party-npm-modules)), because the DOM isn't ready during the execution of `rendered` callback.

```
Template.deliveryForm.rendered = function(){
  Meteor.defer(function() {
    $('select.dropdown').dropdown('clear');
  });
}
```

Hope this works now :)

Comment: Thanks @Carlos Rodrigues but it doesn't work, already tried that instead of my  $('select.dropdown').dropdown(); .. :/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's your function case to do tha but I think after submiting your form, you want just to reset your dropdown(select your first option).
Try the code below:

```
Template.deliveryForm.events({
  'submit .new-delivery': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var date = event.target.date.value;
    var brand = event.target.brand.value;
    var description = event.target.description.value;

    Deliveries.insert({
        date: date,
        brand: brand,
        description: description,
        createdAt: new Date()
    });

    event.target.date.value = "";

    //Below code will restore defaults of your dropdown
    $('.dropdown').dropdown('restore defaults');

    event.target.description.value = "";
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @GUISSOUMAIssam, I've tried something like this before and retried your code in the event function but doesn't work neither :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, it seems to work, but with your both answers .... here is the code, but could not explain why ...

```
Meteor.subscribe('brands');

Template.deliveryForm.helpers({
  brands: function() {
    return Brands.find({}, {fields: {'brand':1}});
  }
});

Template.deliveryForm.events({
 'submit .new-delivery': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var date = event.target.date.value;
    var brand = event.target.brand.value;
    var description = event.target.description.value;

    Deliveries.insert({
        date: date,
        brand: brand,
        description: description,
        createdAt: new Date()
    });

    event.target.date.value = "";
    $('.dropdown').dropdown('restore defaults');
    event.target.description.value = "";
 }
});

Template.deliveryForm.rendered = function(){
  Meteor.defer(function() {
    $('.dropdown').dropdown('restore defaults');
  });
}
```

Thanks again :)